# Hi, Im converting MYSQL returned data into PHP array. but i dont know how to add double quotes to the values

Tags: php, arrays, json, double-quotes

This the code im using to create an array in PHP from the MYSQL returned data:-

```
foreach($empRecords->result_array() as $row) {
      $tid = $row['transaction_id'];
      $checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="'.$tid.'">';
        $data[] = array(
                $checkbox, 
                $row['transaction_id'],
                $row['member_id'],
                $row['member_name'],
            );
  }
```

The result I'm getting is:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <input type="checkbox"  class="CheckedarrayCount" name="check[]" value="247">
            [1] => 247
            [2] => 101257
            [3] => Nithin
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => <input type="checkbox"  class="CheckedarrayCount" name="check[]" value="249">
            [1] => 249
            [2] => 101258
            [3] => Rekha
        )
)
```

But this is the kind I'm getting the result I'm getting:-

```
{
    "data": [
        ["\u003Cinput type=\"checkbox\"  class=\"CheckedarrayCount\" name=\"check[]\" value=\"247\"\u003E", "247", "101257", Nithin\u003C\/a\u003E", ],
        ["\u003Cinput type=\"checkbox\"  class=\"CheckedarrayCount\" name=\"check[]\" value=\"249\"\u003E", "249", "101258", "ERekha\u003C\/a\u003E"],

}
```

Please help!

Comment: What kind of result you want can you please let me know?

Comment: Unnecessary unicode. Why were the results stored that way in the first place? You should just store data in the database. Build the DOM on the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should encode the html characters in **PHP** while creating array

Use [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
$checkbox = htmlspecialchars('<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="'.$tid.'">', ENT_QUOTES);
```

or use [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

```
$checkbox = htmlentities('<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="'.$tid.'">');
```

If you want to use **Javascript** while parsing the returned string

```
<script>
// console.log(decodeURIComponent(YOUR_STRING))
console.log(decodeURIComponent('\u003c'));
</script>
```